# Acceptability of the two sentences.?

Tags: sentence-construction, appositives

I am wondering about if these sentences are right. Since I use this kind of English in my daily life and this gives the intended meaning to me. But English teacher do not agree with me.

---

> A. His parents didn't inherit, I think it was anything to him.
>   (Intended meaning = His parents didn't inherit anything to him.)

---

> B. He killed Sally believes it was himself.   yesterday. (He= himself, same person)

(Intended meaning = He killed himself yesterday.)

---

Comment: I guess your teacher is right.

Comment: The sentences are very difficult to understand. Your teacher **is** right! I wonder if you *know* intended meaning as you yourself write here, why don't you simply practice them?

Comment: I've tried my best to comprehend what you meant with my answer.

Comment: A short comment on definitions: *inherit* means *to receive*.  If you mean that he didn't receive anything from his parents, you would say "He didn't inherit anything" or "His parents didn't **bequeath/will/leave** anything to him."

Answer (score 3):

Your sentences are awkward and can be expressed in a more natural fashion.

You can indeed, I think, insert a remark like *I think* or *Sally believes* in the middle of a sentence as an aside or apposite, but it must be done correctly.

Here are some more natural versions of your two sentences

> His parents, I think, didn't bequeath anything to him.

or

> His parents didn't bequeath, I think, anything to him.

Note *bequeath* means to *leave something to someone, as in a will*, while *inherit* means to receive something from someone when they die.

Another possible structure is

> His parents bequeathed, I don't think, anything to him.

But you could just say

> I don't think his parents bequeathed anything to him.

B.

> He killed himself, Sally believes, yesterday.

or

> He killed, Sally believes, himself yesterday.

Another valid structure is

> Sally believes it was himself that he killed yesterday.

Or you could just say

> Sally believes he killed himself yesterday.

Comment: Apparently I did.

Answer (score 2):

Let me try and help you with these sentences. Try these sentences :

> He did not inherit anything from his parents.

and

> Sally believes that he committed suicide yesterday. (He is someone else, Sally is referred to as 'he')

Keep practicing. I'm sorry if this was of no use at all. Just trying to help.